# An array of length 4-20?

Tags: c, arrays, types, declaration

I'd like for my array to be of a set length using a simple format.  Please, let me know how this is done.

**What I already have:**
`arr[100]`

**Pseudocode: what I would like to have:**
`arr[4-20]` or `arr[$min_int THROUGH $max_int]`

Additional detail edit: The int should be within the range `array = (4, 20)`.  The input may contain leading zeros.  I'd like to keep the length of the array restricted (i.e., to 9 or 10 characters).

Comment: Do you want to make arr[4] first element of array?

Comment: What does arr[4-20] mean? That it will have at least 4 items and no more than 20? How do you ever make one then? It must start empty.

Comment: No.  I see what you mean.  I want an array with 0-1 elements: a limited int or limited "numeric int"--string mimicking an int.

Comment: @freefaller and others: short, elegant, commented code.

Comment: Define "elegant".  This looks like Python to me, which many may consider more elegant than C, but C can be elegant in its own way.  It will never be Python however.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays simply do not work this way in C. You will need to implement it yourself by only looping through valid indices (and wasting memory in the process) or by using a data structure better suited to the job, like a map (which you will have to find in a library or write yourself as it does not exist in the language).

Comment: Ed, it's over my head.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define ARRMINIDX 4
#define ARRMAXIDX 20
int arrmem[ARRMAXIDX+1-ARRMINIDX];
#define arr(x) arrmem[ARRMINIDX+(x)]

// process elements of arr
for( i = ARRMINIDX; i <= ARRMAXIDX; i++ )
    dosomething(arr(i));
```

OTOH, this make not be what you want at all, given your comment

> I want an array with 0-1 elements: a limited int or limited "numeric
>   int"--string mimicking an int.

which I can't make heads or tails of in this context. Are you saying that you want a string of 4-20 chars that represents an integer?